# Stack Address Difference Between Windows 7 and Windows 8.1

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, memory

Consider the following trivial code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int i = -1;
  std::cout << std::hex << &i << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I compile the code on Windows 7 Professional, using Visual Studio 2015 for Desktop, as a 32-bit console application in release mode.  I have ASLR disabled.  If I then transfer the executable to my Windows 8.1 machine, the address of i is different by 8 bytes (it's 8 bytes lower on the Windows 8.1 computer).

1. Why is the stack address different in the two environments?
2. Is there a way -- for example, a linker switch -- to make the stack address the same?

I have tried specifying the target environment linker option, using /FIXED (this is for the program's base address, not the stack), and running the executable in Windows 7 compatibility mode, all to no avail.

To add some context to the question, I'm trying to prepare an example describing how to use the [WriteProcessMemory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681674(v=vs.85).aspx) function.  I was hoping that I could run a trivial executable, built from the code above, and then use WriteProcessMemory to modify i.  It would be great if the address of i was static between pltaforms, because it would simplify my WriteProcessMemory example.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've been asked to discuss the WriteProcessMemory function by some colleagues.  I wrote some simple code, and then read/write to/from the resulting process.  The problem, however, is that my example code only works on Windows 7, because the stack address changes in Windows 8.1.

Comment: why do you need such strict stack address location rules?

Comment: They're different operating systems, why would you expect process memory layout to be identical?

Comment: @Barmar I would not necessarily expect the memory layout to be identical.  My question is what's causing the difference between the two OSs, and if there is a VC++ switch to request the same stack address.

Comment: Most likely it's just a difference in the runtime library. The stack frame that calls `main()` has some extra variables. Or maybe the starting location of the stack is different.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, that seems to be the case.  If you post an answer (e.g. just a "No, this is not possible" along with your comment content) I'll mark your post as the answer.

Comment: I'm not going to post an answer since I don't really know enough about Windows to say anything definitive.

Comment: Windows processes are initialized on the application's stack by OS code that runs in-process. There is no expectation that the loader use exactly the same amount of stack space every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at how a process is created (simplified):

1. OS create the address and process space (from parent process).
2. scheduler switch to the new process and run a stub (now in the created process context), process's kernel stack and application stack is created  (assume 1 kernel and app stack per thread).
3. Enter user mode.
4. the stub pull in executable, libraries and resources. setup extra things like security stuff and initialize handles. Everything uses application's stack.
5. jump to program entrance, the C runtime in your example.
6. crt invoke ctor and do final stuffs.
7. main()

Since C runtime is static linked and didn't change on the two tests, it's also quite simple, I would suspect the process stub being the variable, it has way more works to do too.

By the way, C (and C++) have well documented startup conditions, however stack address is not within the required condition.

PS. Since none of us has windows's code. All we can do is educated guess.

Comment: The OP didn't specify that he's using a statically linked runtime - @avejidah, can you clarify that?

Comment: @davidbak I have tried static linking using the /MT switch.  While it does affect the stack address, the address of i is still different by 8 bytes on the Windows 7 and 8.1 computers.

Comment: even you use msvcrt.dll and they are somehow different in two tests, the startup code (program entrance) is still static linked, the startup code may invoke init functions from the dll, however since that should be C-compatible abi the stack should not change.

Comment: Yes, there's no reason to expect the loader to use the same amount of stack each time.  If you want a variable to be in the same place all the time, you'll have to make it a static variable (and disable relocation).

Comment: Thanks @Harry Johnston, the comment about making the variable static was actually quite helpful, and solves my problem.  I can use static variables for my WriteProcessMemory example, and the static variables have the same address in both environments.  I'm marking Calvin's answer as the accepted one, however, as he does answer my question about why the addresses are different on the stack.